# Error using getSymbols() in quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to randomly select 50 stocks from the New York Stock Exchange, and then get the symbols for them. This code:

```
 require(quantmod)
 NYstocks<-stockSymbols(exchange="NYSE")
 NYsymbols<-NYstocks[["Symbol"]]
 my_portfolio<-sample(NYsymbols, 50, replace = FALSE)
 date_begin <- as.Date("2014-02-18")
 date_end <- as.Date("2016-02-18")
 tickers <- getSymbols(my_portfolio, from = date_begin, to = date_end)
```

gets the error

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
>   more columns than column names

`my_portfolio` is a character vector, so I'm having a hard time figuring out what it means about columns and column names. I've tried using `src="google"` and got

> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("AIW.Open", "AIW.High", "AIW.Low",  : 
>   length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the *Note* in `?stockSymbols` says:

> The symbols returned by `stockSymbols` may not be in the format necessary to retrieve data using `getYahooData`.

And note that `TTR::getYahooData` downloads data from Yahoo Finance, just like `getSymbols.yahoo`.

You should also use `set.seed` when using functions that use the random number generator (i.e. `sample`) so your example will be reproducible.

A couple other things to keep in mind:

1. Yahoo Finance, Google Finance, etc do not necessarily provide historical data for all instruments.
2. Instruments returned by `stockSymbols` are not necessarily equities. They could be tickers for an ETF, ETN, etc.

There are other question/answers about how to use `try` or `tryCatch` to trap errors that may occur because a site doesn't provide historical data.